# predict in LIBLINEAR - Return Value

Tags: matlab

I am using Liblinear in matlab to predict values,
I have some classes and I made each one of them a model using LibLinear.
Now I want to predict for new instance.
I am using the function: 
I am initialize xt to zeros.

[l,a,t]=predict(y, xt, model);

I can't figure out where can I see the probability that the answer that I get is true.
I just get the result in l and don't know where to see the probability for each result.
The t array is values between -3 t0 3 , What is this array?

Thanks
Beno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liblinear does not really outputs probabilities. It just output scores. The score is stored in your "t". A higher score means that it's more likely to be a positive. But there no formal probabilistic reasoning with SVMs.